# Discriminator in OpenApi 3.0.2 polymorphism

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, discriminator

Trying to use OpenApi 3.0.2 to implement polymorphism.

```
Type1:
  type: object
  required:
  - dn
  - typeOfType
  properties:
    dn:
      description: Description
      type: string
    typeOfType:
      type: string
      enum:
        - Type2
        - Type3
  discriminator:
    propertyName: typeOfType
Type2:
  allOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Type1'
  - type: object
    properties:
      name:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/name' #abstract object
    required:
    - name
Type3:
  allOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Type1'
  - type: object
    properties:
      surname:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/surname' #abstract object
    required:
    - surname
```

My generated code looks like :

```
@Validated
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "Discriminator{propertyName&#x3D;&#39;typeOfType&#39;, mapping&#x3D;null}", visible = true )
@JsonSubTypes({
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = WniosekEkwU1.class, name = "Type1"),
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = WniosekEkwU1A.class, name = "Type2"),
})
public class Type1  implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
...
}
```

Summing up, polymorphism is not working. I wonder if my generator works fine when it creates `property = "Discriminator{propertyName&#x3D;&#39;typeOfType&#39;, mapping&#x3D;null}"`. I can not find any example where similar code was generated. 
When i replace this code with `property = "typeOfType"` everything works fine.

Is my code wrong or more configuration is required?

I have also endpoint to test this classes. I receive error:

```
Resolved exception caused by handler execution:  org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
JSON parse error: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class pl.asdf.asdf.asdf.gen.model.type1]: missing type id property 
'Discriminator{propertyName&#x3D;&#39;typeOfType&#39;, mapping&#x3D;null}' (for POJO property 'type1'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: 
Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class pl.asdf.asdf.asdf.gen.model.Type1]: 
missing type id property 'Discriminator{propertyName&#x3D;&#39;typeOfType&#39;, mapping&#x3D;null}' (for POJO property 'type1')
```

I do not get this error when i edit property mentioned above. I guess it is connected. Is there any solution?

Comment: What version of Swagger Codegen did you use? Can you try the latest [3.0.4-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#compatibility)? If the SNAPSHOT also has this issue, file a bug report at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues.

Answer (score 2):

This bug is fixed in the current 3.0.5-SNAPSHOT:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/issues/291

The only thing in your code example I want to mention is to remove the enum definition for the property `typeOfType`

This should be enough:

```
Type1:
  type: object
  discriminator:
    propertyName: typeOfType
  required:
  - dn
  - typeOfType
  properties:
    dn:
      description: Description
      type: string
    typeOfType:
      type: string
```

Comment: Intuitively it would make sense to make discriminators enums, but then again they probably function pretty like enums anyway?